# Непонятный класс EntrySet

Tags: java

В java создаю такую конструкцию. По документации метод `entrySet` возвращает объект типа `Set`, но под отладчиком что-то непонятное. Откуда взялся тип `HashMap@EntrySet`? Вот у переменной `hashMap` тип корректный.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap(1);

hashMap.put(null, 156);
hashMap.put("First", 16);
hashMap.put("Second", 16);

Set set = hashMap.entrySet();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это внутренний класс внутри HashMap, откройте исходники

Comment: [EntrySet](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l1001) - это реализация [абстрактного типа данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) `Set`.

Answer (score 3):

Если откроешь реализацию, то увидишь:

```
final class EntrySet extends AbstractSet<Map.Entry<K,V>>
```

А если перейдешь в реализацию `AbstractSet`:

```
public abstract class AbstractSet<E> extends AbstractCollection<E> implements Set<E>
```

Вот и выходит, что метод `Hashmap.entrySet()` возвращает объект класса `HashMap.EntrySet`, который расширяет абстрактный класс `AbstractSet`, который имплементирует интерфейс `Set`.